# How do I compare two lists without searching for identical strings?

Tags: c#, class, nested, attributes

I have two lists in a C# solution: one for tasks at a factory, and the other for the machines which perform these tasks. When a task is to be performed at station 1, then all machines which are located at station 1 and are able to do the task must be shown.  The tasks and machines are declared in their respective classes of "task" and "machine".

I have come to realise that "foreach" loops do not recognise items from other lists. I do not know how to start a query in one list based on a condition in another list.

class "Machine"

```
class Machine
{
    public string machineName { get; set; }
    public int machineID { get; set; }
    public int Station { get; set; }
    public Function func{ get; set; }

    public Machine(string name = "No Name", int machineid=0, 
    int stat = 0, string functionname = "No Function", bool contact = false)
    {
        machineName = name;
        machineID = machineid;
        Station = stat;
        func = new Function (functionname, contact);
    }
}
```

class "Task"

```
class Task
{
    public string taskName { get; set; }
    public int Station { get; set; }

    public process(string name = "No Name", int stat = 0)
    {
        processName = name;
        Station = stat;
    }
}
```

Main

```
List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
var station1list = taskList.Where(m => m.Station==1).ToList();
foreach (var g in station1list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nThe tasks at station 1: {0}", 
    g.taskName);              
}
```

Expected result: if task A is to be performed at station 1, then the program should search for machines at station 1 which have the associated Function, e.g. "perform task A". This must be repeated for all tasks at all stations.

Comment: What is `Function`? How do you know if a given machine can perform a task? How does a task relate to a function?

Comment: Maybee you should create a data model/class representing a station and the stuff belonging to a station. Basically, your classes should reflect the real scenario: You should have stations, with each station having machines. Currently you just have modelled one giant pile of all machines (one list with all machines) -- which clearly isn't reflecting the scenario you are trying to model here...

Comment: Anyway, if you want to keep your current approach: You alread know how to search and find particular tasks based on some criteria (station). What would prevent you from doing a similar search in the machines list based on some criteria? You already have forumlated that criteria for the machines you want to find (station and function). You already demonstrated there in your code how to search a list of some items based on some criteria. I am utterly confused what/why you are asking here...

Comment: "What would prevent you from doing a similar search in the machines list based on some criteria?" 

The criterion is whether the tasks list contains a specific word. But when I try using the keyword "list.contains", I get an error message saying "cannot convert from 'string' to namespace.Machine"

Comment: Whatever you wrote there that gave you that error (i don't know since your question does not show the code you are referring to in your comment), the error tells you that you tried writing code that treats a simple string object as a Machine object. But as we all know, string objects are not Machine objects, string objects are just that: strings...

Comment: That is my problem. I do not know how to search for words in objects which are not strings.

Answer (score 1):

//Assuming you have a global machines list as well, say,

`machineGlobalList`

```
var station1list = taskList.Where(m => m.Station==1).ToList();
foreach (var g in station1list)
{

     //get machines at station one
     var machinesAtStation = machineGlobalList.Where(x => x.Station == g.Station).ToList();

     //Call their function...
     machinesAtStation.ForEach(x => x.func = new Function(para1,para2))//pass the respective parameters

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but now Visual Studio tells me that "non-invocable member 'Function' cannot be used like a method".

Comment: Hi, I am sorry but the problem is Function is a class. I have no idea what are you trying to accomplish by invoking the Function constructor like that.